# Jenkins job triggering automatically even though there is no change in the repository claiming the repository is corrupted

Tags: jenkins

I have configured Jenkins to generate builds for the GIT repository in Windows Server. My Jenkins job is configured to Poll the repository continuously and trigger build if any change is found in the repository. The issue is Jenkins job triggers automatically even there is no change in the repository. When I checked the polling log it printed the following message

```
Started on Oct 27, 2011 9:45:54 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Build : #289
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 7fd9fb8139dd0c449a0382b505c7857c8634f33f     (origin/Prod_dev)
Workspace has a .git repository, but it appears to be corrupt.
No Git repository yet, an initial checkout is required
Done. Took 11 sec
Changes found
```

Comment: This has happened to us a lot, I have just raised a [jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11547) on it, please vote/add more info so this can be fixed.

Comment: @james.cookie  Great, I was trying to report that issue in JIRA yesterday but for some reason JIRA was throwing some exception while creating a new issue. I'm glad you already reported one there. I already voted for that issue in JIRA, let's hope it will be fixed soon in next release.

Comment: There is a pull-request with the fix, but not sure why it was closed. Check it out: https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/41